# ESP8266 boot mode:(3,7) after flashing

Tags: arduino, esp8266, boot

After I flashed my EP8266-01 with the tool from Espressif and the Nonos SDK I restartet it and received following error message:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:1, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x40100000, len 2592, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xef
load 0x00000000, len 0, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0xef
load 0x00000000, len 0, room 0 
tail 0
chksum 0xef
csum 0xef
csum err
ets_main.c
```

The ESP8266-01 is connected to FTDI232 modul as seen here:

[image]

My Properties of the Flash Software:

[image]

What have I done wrong and causes this error message?